# How do you tile a texture across a surface in React VR?

Tags: webvr, react-360

I have a box 100m x 100m to act as a floor in a reactVR test I am working on, I'd like to add a texture to it but the tile texture just stretches over the entire surface rather than tile, as desired. Here is my component code, nothing special:

```
    <Box
      dimWidth={100}
      dimDepth={100}
      dimHeight={0.5}
      texture={asset('check_floor_tile.jpg')}
      style={{
        color:'#333333',
        transform: [{translate: [0, -1, 0]}]
      }}
      lit
    />
```

I've had a look for examples without success, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to change the way textures are wrapped, at the moment it's hardcoded to `THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping` with no way to change it to `THREE.RepeatWrapping` for ex. See [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/55) on Github.

Comment: Thanks for the update Valentin, its appreciated. I'll keep an eye on release notes to see how it matures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now tile a texture across a surface by using specifying `repeat` on the texture property of any component that extends `BasicMesh` (Box, Plane, Sphere, Cylinder, Model).

The functionality has been added to Reach VR via [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/pull/340).

```
<Plane
  texture={{
    ...asset('texture.jpg'),
    repeat: [4, 4],
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Wunderbar! I kiss all 4 of your cheeks sir, thank you. Thanks for taking the time to let me know, its appreciated!